# Oracle Data Pump Export

Tags: oracle, datapump

I am trying to perform Oracle Data pump Export (using API) over a network link on a server running linux.

When I run the API I get the following error:

```
ORA-31693: Table data object TABLE NAME failed to load/unload and is being skipped 
due to error: ORA-30657: operation not supported on external organized table.
```

The export works fine with `expdp` command, plus the tables are not external.

I am using DATA PUMP API as follows

```
    jobNo:= DBMS_DATAPUMP.OPEN ('EXPORT','SCHEMA',NetworkLINK,'EXPORT_JOB123','LATEST');
   DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE(
   handle => jobNo,
   filename => DumpFilename,
   directory =>Directory name );
```

The procedure seems to run fine, when I use the SYSTEM schema. But still the errors persist from other schemas.

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory; you are trying to populate an external table. You can't do that through standard means. You must populate this using an API that calls UTL_FILE or something similar.

Comment: I understand that but, the tables in the database are not created as external. The API exports none of the tables in the schema. I am receiving the same error for all of the tables.

Comment: So when you say you're using the API, can you provide an example of the code you're using to do just that?

Comment: I am using bash script to call the Data Pump API which is saved as stored procedure in a Oracle DB. (Both script and stored procedure exist in same server)

Comment: Don't add code in comments. ***Edit*** your question and add the code

Comment: Just curious.... *why* are you calling a bash script to call the DATAPUMP API? Why not just use expdp?

Comment: I need to monitor the the process, get information related to the dump file and populate the information in a table. Need to get access to Job Status, Job Desc among other things.